# Metamask signing. What does it do?

Tags: metamask

Okay, so I went into cryptomoonshot.net and voted for a coin. But to get in there, I had to "Sign" my wallet to log in.

What is this feature in metamask? Does it give the webpage access to my wallet, or is it a beneign way of actually proving you own this wallet?

(Also cryptomoonshot.net is BSC i think and not ETH, but don't really know where else i should ask this question)